# Mhchem errors in LyX: kernel/command not defined and undefined control sequence

Tags: errors, lyx, mhchem, undefined, compilation-error

I'm using MiKTeX (Console) 2.9.6673 on a Windows 10 Pro. Consider the following minimal-not-working-example.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mhchem}

\begin{document}
\ce{H2O}
\end{document}
```

The document body contains nothing else but `\ce{}`, and it doesn't compile, throwing tons of errors. I don't understand the problem. I have every required package (mhchem, chemgreek, l3kernel, l3packages). Some errors:

```
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
!
! LaTeX error: "kernel/command-not-defined"
! 
! Control sequence \regex_match:NnTF undefined.
! 
! See the LaTeX3 documentation for further information.
! 
! For immediate help type H <return>.
!............................................... 

l.53 ...nerate_variant:Nn \regex_match:NnTF { NV }

|'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
| This is a coding error.
| 
| LaTeX has been asked to use a control sequence '\regex_match:NnTF':
| this has not been defined yet.
|...............................................
```

[Here](https://gist.github.com/InteLStaT/8450e3892b196869aeacf91bc4edcfb4)'s the complete log (first error on line 375). They all seem to contain something regex-related. What can I do to solve this?

Comment: This is a more-than-minimal example. Start throwing out all unnecessary packages and package options while the errors are still showing, or stop showing: Magyar, geometry, babel, ams packages, version=3 in mhchem, hyperref,  etc. You can't call the same package with different options twice. Any difference between \ce{H2O} and $\ce{H2O}$?

Comment: Threw out everything. Everything stayed the same.

Comment: Instead of `l3regex`, you could try updating the `l3`-packages via the MikTeX console, for both user and admin. You have an `expl3` from 2016, a lot of things has happened since then.

Answer (score 1):

It seems placing `\usepackage{l3regex}` *before* `\usepackage{mhchem}` solves the problem. I'm not sure why `l3regex` is not included by default by `mhchem` if it makes use of the former, I didn't have a problem with this before reinstalling MiKTeX.

Comment: I quote from my LaTeX output: "Package l3regex is obsolete and has been removed! Its functionality is now only provided as part of the expl3 package. The old packages will be removed entirely at the end of 2018. Therefore, please replace '\usepackage{l3regex}' with '\usepackage{expl3}' in your documents as soon as possible."

Answer (score 1):

You do not have the current `expl3` package installed and are missing the `l3regex` functionality.

You could try using `\usepackage{l3regex}`, but that is not a good solution. In my output, this writes

> ** Package l3regex is obsolete and has been removed!
>   **
>   ** Its functionality is now only provided as part of the expl3 package.
>   **
>   ** The old packages will be removed entirely at the end of 2018.
>   **
>   ** Therefore, please replace '\usepackage{l3regex}'
>   ** with '\usepackage{expl3}' in your documents as soon as possible.

Comment: I have `expl3` installed as part of `l3kernel`, and `mhchem.sty` also contains the line `\RequirePackage{expl3}`, but it doesn't work like that. If I add `\RequirePackage{l3regex}` to `mhchem.sty`, everything works perfect. I understand it's obsolete, but why doesn't it work with just `expl3` if it contains `l3regex`'s functionality?

Answer (score 0):

Adding `\RequirePackage{l3regex}` to `mhchem.sty` solved the problem. This is useful if you can't put `\usepackage{l3regex}` before `\usepackage{mhchem}`. For example in LyX, if LyX automatically loads the package when you insert a chemical formula.